# How can i adapt accuracy metric for multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, metric, scoring, model-evaluations

I have a problem which is multiclass e.g. That is 4 classes. I would like a custom metric to assess the model where only if class 3 is predicted as class 2 and class 2 is predicted as class 3 (i.e. those in the middle) then it is penalized less.

How can i do this by adapting the sklearn accuracy_score metric of similar?

e.g. comparing:

```
predicted_labels = [1,3,0,0,2..]
actual = [0,0,2,1,3,3...]
```

Comment: Can you apply a weighting system?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but why not implementing a custom evaluation function?

Comment: how can i do that